# How to use relative links for my hexo blog as thumbnails?

Tags: node.js, hexo

I want to use relative links for my image assets in hexo to display them as thumbnails, i am using the `hueman` theme and so i have the following post(only header part shown below):

```
---
title: ChocolateLove
date: 2018-05-08 04:55:56
tags: [css, chocolate]
thumbnail: /ChocolateLove/choco.jpg
---
```

Using the hueman theme you can set the thumbnail for the post like above , but this does't work , in the browser console i get a 404 error for the image resource, of course if i use a image from the web , I.E. like so:

```
---
title: APostAboutCss
date: 2018-05-08 03:38:38
tags: [CSS , jQuery]
thumbnail: https://matthewhorne.me/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/coding-screen-1280x500.jpg
---
```

The thumbnail displays and renders perfectly fine.So my question is how do i use relative links in my hexo blog ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was changing:

```
thumbnail: /ChocolateLove/choco.jpg
```

to this

```
thumbnail: /2018/05/08/ChocolateLove/choco.jpg
```

Basically you append the `YY/MM/DD` from the date attribute, as can we seen below:

```
---
title: ChocolateLove
date: 2018-05-08 04:55:56
tags: [css, chocolate]
thumbnail: /2018/05/08/ChocolateLove/choco.jpg
---
```